# Active Record query based on property of has_many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, merge, active-record-query

Here's a common occurrence. I have a parent category, say `Category`. It has_many child categories, say `Books`. Books have a property `published`, and I want to get all Categories that have published books. How do I do that?

---

I could loop through the Categories to find them, but I want a better way. In [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3?view=asciicast), he suggests using the following query: `Category.joins(:products).merge(Product.cheap)`, or `Subject.joins(:books).merge(Book.published)` in my example. However, I don't have a scope `published` in `Book`.

I have a method `all_published` in `Book` that returns all published books, so I tried `Category.joins(:books).merge(Book.all_published)` but it contained duplicate categories. What's the best general way to solve this common problem?

Comment: `.joins` makes duplicates, `.includes` does not: `Category.includes(:books).merge(Category.all_published)` should work for you

Comment: @MrYoshiji, that works. I guess that's the best way then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.joins` makes duplicates, whereas `.includes` does not.

In your case, the following should work:

```
Category.includes(:books).merge(Book.all_published)
```